# Working with local and remote GIT repository

Tags: git, version-control

There are two GIT servers - *main* remote server A and local server B. Normally I push&pull changes to server A and only push to server B. However sometimes remote server A is unavailable for me and I push&pull my changes only to server B. Meanwhile someone can push something to server A. When remote server A is available again, I would like as earlier to push&pull to server A and only push to server B. Would there be some problem with synchronizing these two servers? What should be order of pushing and pulling? How can be solved such work with local and remote server in a good manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is why you need to merge. You pull from A, merge changes in your local repo and push back to both A and B. You should not look on remote servers as servers but like on people each working on their own branches when you pull from.